# Hierarchy of checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny

I have 3 different geographical levels in my ui.R : the global level (Level 1), which contains 3 sub levels (Level 2), which each level contains 3 sub levels (Level 3).

The 3 first levels of Level 3 are contained in the first level of Level 2, the next 3 levels of Level 3 are contained in the second level of Level 2,
the last 3 levels of Level 3 are contained in the third level of Level 2.

How can I get all the check boxes checked when the Level 1 check box is checked ? And if I check the 3 first levels of Level 3, how to get the first level of Level 2 checked automatically.

Here is the ui code :

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(navbarPage("RP 2014",
     tabPanel("Sélection",
         print (h4(strong("Geographical levels"))),
             fluidRow(
                 column(width = 3,
                     h5(strong("Level 1")),
                        checkboxInput("dynamic_L1",
                               label = "")
                            ), # f. column
                  column(width = 3,
                        checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_L2",
                                label = h5(strong("Level 2")),
                                   choices = list("L2_1"  = "Level 2-1",
                                                   "L2_2" = "Level 2-2",
                                                   "L2_3" = "Level 2-3"))
                         ),
                   column(width = 3,
                         checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_L3",
                                label = h5(strong("Level 3")),
                                    choices = list("L3_1" = "Level 3-1",
                                                   "L3_2" = "Level 3-2",
                                                   "L3_3" = "Level 3-3",
                                                   "L3_4" = "Level 3-4",
                                                   "L3_5" = "Level 3-5",
                                                   "L3_6" = "Level 3-6",
                                                   "L3_7" = "Level 3-7",
                                                   "L3_8" = "Level 3-8",
                                                   "L3_9" = "Level 3-9"))
                           )
                           )
                      )
                )     
  )
```

I hope my question is understandable, thank you for helping me.

Comment: I don't have a complete answer, but I'd start by having a look at using a `reactive` function to be called under the circumstances you describe, containing an `updateCheckboxGroupInput` function to change the selected inputs.

Comment: Have you checked the [shinytree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyTree/README.html) package?

Comment: Use a combination of `oberserveEvent` and `updateCheckboxGroupInput`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @warmoverflow suggested, use `observeEvent` and `updateCheckboxGroupInput`. You should get the gist of it from the example.

Code:

```
library(shiny)

l2_choices <- list("L2_1"  = "Level 2-1",
                   "L2_2" = "Level 2-2",
                   "L2_3" = "Level 2-3")

l3_choices <- list("L3_1" = "Level 3-1",
                   "L3_2" = "Level 3-2",
                   "L3_3" = "Level 3-3",
                   "L3_4" = "Level 3-4",
                   "L3_5" = "Level 3-5",
                   "L3_6" = "Level 3-6",
                   "L3_7" = "Level 3-7",
                   "L3_8" = "Level 3-8",
                   "L3_9" = "Level 3-9")

lvl3_f3 <- l3_choices[1:3]
lvl2_f1 <- l2_choices[1]

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("RP 2014",
                         tabPanel("Sélection",
                                  print (h4(strong("Geographical levels"))),
                                  fluidRow(
                                    column(width = 3,
                                           h5(strong("Level 1")),
                                           checkboxInput("dynamic_L1",
                                                         label = "")
                                    ), # f. column
                                    column(width = 3,
                                           checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_L2",
                                                              label = h5(strong("Level 2")),
                                                              choices = l2_choices)
                                    ),
                                    column(width = 3,
                                           checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_L3",
                                                              label = h5(strong("Level 3")),
                                                              choices = l3_choices)
                                    )
                                  )
                         )
)     
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  observeEvent(input$dynamic_L1, {
    # Get all the checkboxes checked when the Level 1 checkbox is checked
    if(input$dynamic_L1){
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic_L2", selected = l2_choices)
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic_L3", selected = l3_choices)
    }
  observeEvent(input$dynamic_L3, {
    # Get the first level of Level 2 checked automatically when the 3 first levels of Level 3 are checked
    if (all(lvl3_f3 %in% input$dynamic_L3)) {
      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, inputId = "dynamic_L2", selected = c(input$dynamic_L2, lvl2_f1))
    }
  })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions: @rosscova, thank you for your suggestion, I think it's a good idea. @ Valter, thank you too, your idea is very interesting but. Unfortunately, aspect of shinyTree does not match this part of the application. I'll use it in another part of my program. @ warmoverflow and GyD, thank you very much, I like your proposal, but as I'm new to R, it's a little bit difficult for me right now to setup checked/unchecked under conditions. So, finally, I will use conditionalPanel that simplier as I have a lot of other check boxes to add. Thank you very much again.